# Parse: Expiry time on Array Value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, ios9

So in Parse, I upload an array that is populated with values from user submissions.

Is there anyway to set an expiry time (of an hour preferably) on a single value that is submitted by the user.

In essence, as soon as the value is submitted, a "timer" (for lack of better terms" is started and the value is deleted from the array after an hour?

After the value is deleted, I want the array's average value to be recalculated and displayed back into the part of the app that displays the array's average value.

I think it has to deal with server side stuff not anything within the Xcode project itself.

I was thinking something along the lines of when the object is submitted giving it a `createdAt` value and then running an if statement that compares the `currentTime` to the `object.createdAt` value.

Any help? I apologize, I'm fairly new to Parse and understanding the whole animal.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creating an object for each user submission is acceptable, I would suggest you do so.

Each entry thus automatically gets an createdAt time by parse.com at time of creation.

The entries should have a Pointer to the user, this way you can query the answers made by a specific user.

Next you would need to investigate the Cloud Code part of parse. I would claim that you, with above construction, easily can write a background job that deletes all entries that are older than an hour.

Finally schedule the background job to run every 30 minutes or so.

Hope you get the idea and that my input is helpful to you.